# python highcharts integration issue with loading script in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, highcharts, visualization

I encounter this issue while integrating highcharts into my python application with https://github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-core

```
Something went wrong with the Highcharts.js script. It should have been automatically loaded, but it did not load for over 3 seconds. Check your internet connection, and then if the problem persists please reach out for support.
```

This looks like a issue with loading the core scripts. Quick help or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry you're running into this issue! Several questions to help diagnose the issue that is happening:
1. What version of Highcharts Core for Python are you using?
2. What version of Jupyter Notebook / Jupyter Lab are you using?
3. Are you using Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab?
4. Are you using them in your browser directly, or via an IDE like VSCode?
5. If using VSCode, are you using any VSCode / extensions related to Jupyter Notebook / Labs?

The answers to these questions will help diagnose what may be happening here. Thanks!

Comment: I recently had the similar issue (mine says 5 seconds) when using a notebook on VSCode, but the same notebook opened in Jupyter Notebook on browser had no issues.
- highcharts core for py: v1.3.7
- jupyter: v1.0.0
- vscode ext: all 4 from Jupyter ext. pack, Jupyter PowerToys. All by MSFT

Comment: Hi @Sai - In your case, this is likely tied to [this issue](https://github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-core/issues/46). It's a difficult problem, because it is very difficult to reproduce consistently. Some users report that disabling the Jupyter-related extensions, restarting VSCode, and then enabling the extensions again helps. We suspect that it may have to do with the order in which the extensions were initially installed, or possibly the order in which they are disabled / enabled, but we haven't (yet) been able to find the exact pattern to reproduce / resolve it consistently.